# Mysql sum on self table select

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm looking for the right sql query to do the following operation:
I need to display all record for today and for each make sum of price field for the curent user and date < today

Table Commandes: (today = 11/18/2022)

| ID | username | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user.1 | 11/21/2022 | 99.0 |
| 2 | user.x | 11/21/2022 | 99.0 |
| 3 | user.1 | 11/18/2022 | 2.5 |
| 4 | user.x | 11/18/2022 | 10.0 |
| 5 | user.1 | 11/17/2022 | 2.5 |
| 6 | user.x | 11/17/2022 | 20.0 |
| 7 | user.1 | 11/16/2022 | 2.5 |
| 8 | user.x | 11/16/2022 | 30.0 |

I want:

```
| ID       | username | date       | price  | solde
| -------- | -------- |------------|------- |------
| 1        | user.1   | 11/18/2022 |  2.5   |  5.0
| 2        | user.x   | 11/18/2022 | 10.0   | 40.0
```

solde would be same as "backorder not yet payed". When Item is payed, field price is set to 0.

For now, i use this query:

SELECT * FROM Commandes WHERE (Date='11/18/2022')

And in each row I execute:

```
SELECT sum(price) as solde 
FROM Commandes 
WHERE (username=currentselecteduser) and (STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') < CURDATE());
```

That's working but really uggly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
SELECT t1.* , 
(select sum(price) from Commandes where username = t1.username and date < CURDATE()) solde 
FROM `Commandes` as t1 
WHERE date = CURDATE()
```

Also would like the tell you something that,
You want the total for the dates < today, so As per your logic  your for user.x  total will be 50  nor  40

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It's easy when we receive some help !
A mistake I had also made during my tests, a capital letter instead of a lowercase! :(
Thank you for this clear and precise explanation !

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT username, 
       `date`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `date` = CURRENT_DATE THEN price END) price,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `date` < CURRENT_DATE THEN price END) solde
FROM Commandes 
WHERE `date` <= CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

The query assume that

1. `` (username, `date`) `` is defined as UNIQUE;
2. `date` is stored in the column which have DATE datatype.